# Please cast an eye over my beginners javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on [an interface](http://andartmedia.com/un/squares) with four main parts:

1. When a category link is hovered, the projects not in this category are darkened (this seems to be working ok)
2. When a category link is clicked, the projects not in this category are hidden (seems also to be ok)
3. The browser window size is detected and a style sheet is chosen to fit. I.e. for older screen or mobile. Go ahead and resize the browser window.
4. When the browser window is narrow there is an additional script to scroll down to the "main" div.

   ```
   <div id="container">
   <div id="inner-container">
   <div id="tag-selector">
       <ul>
           <li class="all">ALL PROJECTS</li>
   <li class="graphic-design">graphic design</li>
           <li class="logo-design">logo design</li>
           <li class="photography">photography</li>
           <li class="web-development">web development</li>
           <li class="web-design">web design</li>
       </ul>
   </div> 
   <div id="main" role="main"> 
   <p class="items">There are x items in this category</p>
   <p class="selected">No category selected</p>
   <p class="clicked">No category clicked</p>
       <section class="graphic-design">
           <p>graphic-design</p>
       </section>
       <section class="logo-design graphic-design">
           <p>logo-design</p><p> graphic-design</p>
       </section>
       <section class="logo-design graphic-design"><p>etc</p>
       </section>

   </div>
   <footer> </footer>
   ```

then here's the javascript. Sorry if it's a bit long.  It should be easy enough to read I hope.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var xwidth =$(window).width();//get width of user window
    all_projects_showing_text="All projects showing. There are " + n + " projects, in " + t + " categories.";
    adjustStyle(xwidth);
    $("p.items").text(all_projects_showing_text + " Width=" + xwidth);
    $(".all").addClass("selected");
    tag="all"
});
</script>

    <script>
var n = $("section").length;//number of section boxes on page
var t = $("#tag-selector li").length;//categories
t--;

 $("#tag-selector li").click(function() {//clicking section filter li
    $("#tag-selector li").removeClass("selected");//removes all filtered class
    $(this).addClass("selected");//then adds it to the chosen link (li), showing it as current
    tag=$(this).attr("class");//var tag is the class name of the chosen link, i.e. category
    var split = tag.split(' '); // this splits the class string and puts each item in an array
    tag = split[0];//this chooses the first item of the array, hence not including the hilite class
    var numItems = $('.'+tag).length
    var numItems=numItems-1;//correct for real number

    if (tag!="all"){//if the all link is not picked
    $("section").hide();// hide all the boxes
    $("#main ."+tag).fadeIn();//show all the boxes with the tag class
        if(tag=="graphic-design"){
          tag="Graphic design"
        }
        else if(tag=="logo-design"){
          tag="Logo design"
        }
        else if(tag=="photography"){
          tag="Photography"
        }
        else if(tag=="web-development"){
          tag="Web development"
        }
        else if(tag=="web-design"){
          tag="Web design"
        }

        $("p.items").text(numItems+" " +tag+ " projects");
        $("p.selected").text(tag +" selected.");
        $("p.clicked").text(tag +" selected.");
    }
    else{
      $("section").fadeIn();//else show all the boxes
      $("p.items").text(all_projects_showing_text);// all_projects_showing_text at onReady 
    }       
});
</script>

    <script>
  $("#tag-selector li").hover(function () {

    hovered_link=$(this).attr("class");//get the class of the category being hovered
    var split = hovered_link.split(' '); // this returns an array
    hovered_link = split[0];//remove any other classes apart from the first i.e. remove hilite

    if (tag=="all"){// if All are shown
        if(hovered_link!="all"){
          $("section").not("."+hovered_link).addClass("section_darkened");//darken section which does not correspond with hovered category link
          $("section").not(".section_darkened").addClass("outerglow");//add glow to not darkened sections
        }
    }
    else{
    }
    if (tag==hovered_link){// if the projects are already filtered by this category, say so on hover
        $("p.selected").text(tag +" already selected.");
    }
    else{
        var numItems = $('.'+hovered_link).length
        var numItems=numItems-1;//correct for real number
        $("p.selected").text("Click to see only "+hovered_link+ " projects. (" +numItems+ " projects)" );
    }

    $(this).addClass("hilite");//hilite on hover over link
    }, function () {
      $(this).removeClass("hilite");
      $("p.selected").text("...");
      $("section").removeClass("section_darkened");//darken categories not in the selected category
      $("section").removeClass("outerglow");//give the selected category items a glow
    });
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});

function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 600) {
        $("#tag-selector li").click(function() {// SCroll function for handhelds
        $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#main").offset().top},
                'slow');
        });
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/nav-style-narrow.css");//style sheet for handhelds
    } else if ((width >= 440)&&(width < 1040)){
      $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/nav-style-med.css");
    } else {
      $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/nav-style-wide.css");
    }
}
</script>
```

If you've gotten this far and had a look, thanks!

So my questions are;

1. <strike>Am I missing `break;` in my loops anywhere? Not too sure how to use break.</strike>
2. When my CSS file is chosen, there is a flash of the first style before it changes. Is there a way to avoid this?
3. When the browser is at the narrowest style sheet, and I click on my link, I have problems scrolling back up again afterwards. help?! :-)
4. Any glaring mistakes or omissions that would make this easier?
5. I start to feel like I have a lot of script on my one page. Maybe I should put it in a separate file. Would that help?
6. Is it ok to post multiple questions like this or should they be individual?

Thanks in advance for anyone who has a look.

Comment: I can't help but +1 for your attempt and for posting code. Thanks!

Comment: It would probably be better to post each question individually.  Try to keep it as narrow and easily reproducible as possible to make it easier for people to answer.  For the more general questions which are not directly issues, you may want to consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks for the encouragement anyway :-)

Comment: You should probably post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Try dumping it into a jsFiddle at least - it took a bit of cleanup to even get it this far (spaces between slashes make invalid comments) http://jsfiddle.net/G5ddS/1/

Comment: First, I do not see a loop :). `break` is used to break out of a loop such as `for` or `while`. For development you can have the JS in the page, but it is common to have the code in a seperate file.

Comment: Great points. Exactly what I was looking for. Conditional is not a loop. Will post on codereview, and trim down to individual questions.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll bite, though I'm not going to try to offer a comprehensive list:

- There are various ways to deal with the CSS flash issue. The easiest is to hide everything until you've loaded the correct stylesheet, then show everything once it's loaded.
- Yes, in general it's always a good idea to put Javascript in separate files - it just makes managing your code easier, especially if you want to reuse any of it on multiple pages.
- You're missing a lot of `var` statements, e.g. for `all_projects_showing_text`. This is syntactically correct, but a Bad Idea in Javascript, because it makes those variables global, attaching them to the `window` object. If you need a global variable, you should still declare it with `var`.
- I'm not seeing any place where `break` would be appropriate, or even possible. You generally use `break` within a `for` or `while` loop to stop looping; I'm not seeing any loops like that in your code. JQuery code often uses `.each()` instead, or just loops implicitly through all the items in the selection; I rarely see `break` in code using jQuery, though there are of course times when it might be appropriate.
- It's often a good idea to either cache or chain jQuery selectors. For example,

  ```
  $("section").removeClass("section_darkened");
  $("section").removeClass("outerglow");
  ```

  could be

  ```
  var $section = $section;
  $section.removeClass("section_darkened");
  $section.removeClass("outerglow");
  ```

  or

  ```
  $("section")
      .removeClass("section_darkened")
      .removeClass("outerglow");
  ```

  or even (in this case, since `.removeClass()` can remove several classes at once):

  ```
  $("section")
      .removeClass("section_darkened outerglow");
  ```
- Your long `else if` section starting `if(tag=="graphic-design"){` could be better structured as a map + lookup:

  ```
  var tagTitles = {
      "graphic-design":"Graphic design",
      "logo-design":"Logo design",
      // etc
  };
  tag = tagTitles[tag];
  ```

Comment: thanks Nick. So how about my `tag` variable used in the `.click` function, since it is also used by my `.hover` function. Is it ok to be global in this case?

Comment: It's okay to have a global variable, but you want to make it *explicit* - either declare it with `var tag;` in the global scope, refer to it as `window.tag`, or put it in a custom namespace in the global scope.

Comment: thanks again Nick. having a good look at your suggestions today. map + lookup is one I will remember.

Comment: Glad this was useful. It's not quite as legible, but you can even use a concise version for a one-time lookup: `tag = { ... }[tag]`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer regarding `break`:

`break` stops the execution of the current loop or `switch`. You should use it in loops in order to stop a loop before the end of the current iteration, or on a condition that is not checked in the loop statement itself. You should use it at the end of a `case` in a `switch` block in order not to execute subsequent `case`s.

In your specific code there don't seem to be any loops or `switch`es, so no place for any `break` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

1. `break` is not a function. It's a statement, so you don't add parenthesis.
2. The page loads before the css is choosen. If you want to target different screen sizes, you could take a look at [css3 media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). Adding the styles at the beginning of the page should work without flickering. You could still use js to choose styles as backup method.
3. I think you are adding a new click handler on *every* resize event! That's a lot of animations running on a click, try to set the handler only once.
4. Missing `var`, as already mentioned by nrabinowitz. Indentation could be better / more consistent.
5. JS in Separate files is better.

   - cacheable by clients -> page gets faster after first visit
   - reusable by different pages
   - easier to manage (version control)
6. Single (well researched) questions are generally better.